# Drawing an Image to a subItem in the ListView

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

My Listview is setup in the details view with the following column headers:

Image Name || Image Location || Image Size || Image Preview

I would like to know if there is a way to draw an image in the 4th column there.  The only way I know, is to set

```
this.listview1.OwnerDraw = true
this.listView1.DrawColumnHeader += new System.Windows.Forms.DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventHandler(listView1_DrawColumnHeader);
this.listView1.DrawItem += new System.Windows.Forms.DrawListViewItemEventHandler(listView1_DrawItem);
this.listView1.DrawSubItem += new System.Windows.Forms.DrawListViewSubItemEventHandler(listView1_DrawSubItem);
```

The problem with this is I have to handle ALL the listview drawing myself...
I was wondering if there is a better way to draw in image to a subItem, or if there is a way to only handle the DrawSubItem event?

Comment: I don't need to draw the Column Header or Draw the Item...only the SubItem.  But when I set OwnerDraw = true, I am forced to draw all 3.  Is there a way to only have to draw the SubItem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `listView1_DrawColumnHeader` and `listView1_DrawItem` event handlers you should put this

```
e.DrawDefault = true;
```

It will use default drawing implementation for columns and items, all you have to do is write your own implementation only for subitems.

Answer (score 7):

I just ran into this.

[@zidane's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050185/drawing-an-image-to-a-subitem-in-the-listview/1259074#1259074) is nearly correct. I want to post what actually needs to be done so people reading back later don't have to figure this out themselves.

---

Only handle `DrawColumnHeader` using `e.DrawDefault = true;` and the subitem drawing. In fact, if you set `e.DrawDefault = true;` in the `DrawItem` event, the `DrawSubItem` event never fires, presumably on the assumption that you want to draw the whole row and don't care about the subitems.

The only real code is in `DrawSubItem`, using this basic construction:

```
if (/* condition to determine if you want to draw this subitem */)
{
    // Draw it
}
else
    e.DrawDefault = true;
```

Answer (score 3):

[ObjectListView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/objectlistview.aspx) (an open source wrapper around a .NET WinForms ListView) trivially supports drawing images in columns without having to do all the owner drawing yourself. The Data tab of the demo shows animated GIFs, which is a bit OTT but it will work equally well with static images.

With a few lines of code, this is what your ListView can look like:
[image]
<sub>(source: [sourceforge.net](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/_images/fancy-screenshot.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Building upon previous answers, here's a full VB.NET example:

```vb
Public Class MyListView : Inherits System.Windows.Forms.ListView

Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New()
    MyBase.OwnerDraw = True
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnDrawSubItem(ByVal e As DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs)
    If x Then ' condition to determine if you want to draw this subitem
        ' draw code goes here
    Else
        e.DrawDefault = True
    End If
    MyBase.OnDrawSubItem(e)
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnDrawColumnHeader(ByVal e As DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventArgs)
    e.DrawDefault = True
    MyBase.OnDrawColumnHeader(e)
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnDrawItem(e As System.Windows.Forms.DrawListViewItemEventArgs)
    e.DrawDefault = True
    MyBase.OnDrawItem(e)
End Sub

End Class
```