# C# ovalshape on the front on listview

Tags: c#, listview, frontend

I have listview and it doesn't support image in second column. I try create ovalshape, but it olways is on the background of listview. So nobody can see it. I try `ovalShape1.BringToFront();`, but it doesn't work. Anybody can help me?

Comment: Have you done any research? Have you found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.listview.drawsubitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050185/drawing-an-image-to-a-subitem-in-the-listview) or anything..? The keywords are not 'ovalshape' but 'draw subitem'

Comment: I try to do it this way and it works properly, but what I supposed to do when I want to change picture or update it.

Comment: The logic what to draw is handled in the `listView1_DrawItem` event. You must code it for flexibility as needed..

Comment: `listView1_DrawItem` works only when I create item. What can I do to switch pictures of existed item for instance by pressing the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example with an external variable.

I assume you have added your images to an `ImageList imageList1`.

```
int imgIndex = 0;
private void listView1_DrawSubItem(object sender, DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(imageList1.Images[imgIndex], e.Bounds);
    else e.DrawDefault = true;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    imgIndex++;
    listView1.Invalidate();
}
```

You would more likely want to get the imageindex from data in the `ListViewItem` separately for each Row, maybe like this:

```
//..
e.Graphics.DrawImage(imageList1.Images[Convert.ToInt16( e.SubItem.Text) ], e.Bounds);
//..
```

As usual error checking is up to you.

Also note the Invalidate, which triggers the Paint and the subsequent DrawSubItem event, necessary after you have changed the imageindex. When the underlying values change, the system will take care of that.

Comment: Thanks man. I need only function `listView1.Invalidate();` it was crucial. Now it working as I want.